# Pandas returning a copy when using the .at function in a Panel

Tags: python, pandas

All,

I'm currently trying to optimize some sub-routines of a small backtesting app I've built for myself. I have a 'current_data' pandas panel where all the data is held.

I'm trying to access it as follows:

```
self.current_data.at[order['instrument'], self.current_day, 'low']
```

However, this is very slow. From the documentation, it seems that this should return a view - since I'm not setting any value. I'm using the latest pandas (0.11.0).

Would you be able to tell why this is going on? And maybe a faster way to do this?

By the way, I know that this is a copy because the profiler shows that frame.py:383(**init**) is being called every time, and if I reduce the size of the object this line speeds up tremendously.

Cheers!

Edit:

Here's how to re-create my issue. I see now that the issue is probably not in .at.

```
items = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']


indices = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime.now(), periods=1000, freq="D")
res = {}
for item in items:
    res[item] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=cols, index=indices)

first = pd.Panel(res)

print timeit.Timer("""
for i in range(100, 200):
    today = indices[i]
    first_change = first.ix[:, :i + 1, :]
    first_change.at["A", today, "a"]
    first_change.at["A", today, "b"]
    first_change.at["A", today, "c"]
""", setup="from __main__ import first, indices").timeit(number=50)/50.0

#--- Time: 0.0307311664639

indices = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime.now(), periods=10000, freq="D")
res = {}
for item in items:
    res[item] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 4), columns=cols, index=indices)
second = pd.Panel(res)

print timeit.Timer("""
for i in range(8100, 8200):
    today = indices[i]
    second_change = second.ix[:, :i + 1, :]
    second_change.at["A", today, "a"]
    second_change.at["A", today, "b"]
    second_change.at["A", today, "c"]
""", setup="from __main__ import second, indices").timeit(number=50)/50.0

#--- Time: 0848793384464
```

Anyways, this is basically what's going on. It is probably in the .ix function, but it is simply returning a view so I don't see why it would take more time.

The issue is probably not in .at then, I think.

Comment: This by definition returns a scalar value. If you are enlarging, then it will create and return a new object, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I just need to get a specific scalar from the panel, at a specific position. order['instrument'] is like AAPL, self.current_day is the index of the current day, and 'low' is the column name.
I tried to use ix to perform the same operation but it takes even more time.

Comment: transpose so that your dims are like: items (low) x major (dates) x minor (ids), will give better perf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be measuring something else, `at` is a constant time operation. Pls show some more detail in what you are doing (e.g. a sample panel and accessors)

```
In [24]: p = Panel(randn(1,1,1))

In [25]: %timeit p.at[0,0,0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.33 us per loop

In [26]: p = Panel(randn(10,10,10))

In [27]: %timeit p.at[0,0,0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.34 us per loop

In [28]: p = Panel(randn(100,100,100))

In [29]: %timeit p.at[0,0,0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.28 us per loop

In [30]: p = Panel(randn(1000,1000,1000))

In [31]: %timeit p.at[0,0,0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.36 us per loop
```

Comment: You're right - it's not in .at. Check out the edit.
The strange thing is that the function where the .at is increases in cumulative run time. It could be a bug in cProfile, but I don't really know.

Comment: ``.ix`` in this case might not *always* be returing a view, it actually depends on how numpy is aligning the memory. If you try this with a transposed panel (e.g. your major is your items dim), then I think you will *always* get a view, but since you are iterating over another dim, I am not 100% sure. This could explain the diff.

Comment: Thank you! I've chosen to refactor everything a little bit instead of handling all of these small performance issues. I'm now using dataframes and dictionaries, and it is basically taking 1s to do all the work that was done in 8 seconds before.
Since I don't have to manipulate a lot of ranges/slices, I think this is the best option.